# Column / Table widths overflowing

Tags: tables, spacing, columns, awesome-cv

There should be a simple solution for this table column width problem, but I'm having trouble making it work.

I have taken a CV template and tried to add a (random) company logo to the left of the experience block, but finding a way to do that without impacting the overall width has been challenging.
The Latex is below, followed by an image of the problem.

```
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  % I added this line, creating a table so that the logo can take up the first col
  % and the default company info section can take up the second col
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{} c p{4.5in} @{}}
    % raisebox to center the company logo vertically next to the paragraph of text to the right
    \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=1cm, height=0.25in]{sky_logo.jpeg}}
      \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 8.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
        \ifempty{#2#3}
          {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
          {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
          \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
        \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
      \end{tabular*}%
  \end{tabular}
}
```

Which results in this:
[image]

The tables overflow the text area to the right. Is there an easy fix?

**as requested, [here is a link](https://www.overleaf.com/read/frhrjpdpnmjr) to view the project in overleaf.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! As usual here can you please make your code snippet be compilable resulting in your issue? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: I've included a link for anyone to view the project now hope this helps

Comment: @hungrycable2813 you should have created a new project and redacted your personal information with generic stuff ("first" name, "last" name), your phone number, address etc are all visible. Also, the link may die so it is better to create a smaller example on this website that we can compile and run it without having to go elsewhere.

Comment: I can assure you that the information on the project is not my own and are simply placeholder details (but I appreciate your comment). 

I don't believe the link will die anytime soon, but if it does I'll be sure to replace it!

Comment: The code can't be compiled on its own as is, which makes it very hard to test. Provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) if you can. Not sure why there is a `tabular*` within a `tabular` here, but I doubt `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}` could be right for the inner tabular.

Comment: @hungrycable2813 I tried your link but all I got back was "Join Project" "Project not found". Why haven't you replaced this? DO NOT LINK TO OTHER SOURCES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the original `awesome-cv.cls`  add before `\begin{document}`

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
    \vspace{-2.0mm}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
        \begin{minipage}{1.5cm}\centering\includegraphics[width=1cm, height=0.25in]{sky_logo.jpeg}\end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth-2cm}\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
            \ifempty{#2#3}
            {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
            {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
                \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
            \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
        \end{tabular*}%
    \end{minipage}
}
```

There are two `minipages` side by side: the first with the logo and the second with the tabular.

[image: b]

Comment: Thank you very much! I acknowledge the time taken as some comments mentioned it was hard to test - I'm very grateful